# Angular 2 component as attribute

Tags: angular

I was wondering : how to bind the value of a component used by its selector in the template and an object declared in the model ?

The FormComponent has for selector "interface-form".

Here is the code :

```
@Component({
  moduleId: 'module.id',
  selector: 'create-interface',
  template: '    
<div class="content" style="margin : 20px;">
  <div class="header-section row">
    <button class="btn"> < Retour</button>
  </div>
  <interface-form [data]="data" [dataFields]="this.form.dataFields">
  </interface-form>
</div>'
})

export class CreateComponent {

  public form: FormComponent;
  ...
```

I would like my form attribute to be the instance of interface-form declared in my template, so if i do this :

this.form.addField(...), my template will dynamically change.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Where have to bind the value using attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `FormArray`. Check it out:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html